# GIS server export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I'm changing to a new computer, but I have a lot of GIS Server set on my ArcMAP on my old PC.[image: Check picture below]

Is there a way to export those and import on my new computer? Is there any document telling me how to do that?

I have more than 100 Gis Servers set, it will take long to set one by one.

BTW: I'm using Windows 7 and ArcGIS 10.1 on both computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this but I believe this is a way of transferring your connections. On your old computer navigate to

> Users > (user_name) > AppData > Roaming > ESRI > Desktop10.1 >
> ArcCatalog

You should see a list of files with varying extensions:
[image]

I think if you copy the files for the server connections you want to transfer to your new computer and place them in the same user profile location as above they should show up on your new PC (not sure why they are shown as Windows Media Player Skins in the screenshot maybe because they are WMS connections).